# matTable: UI not updating after altering a datasource row

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm trying to update my dataTable when an user has been edited.

At the moment, the dataSource is updated, but changes are not visible on front part. I mean, my `console.log(this.dataSource)` show good datas. But on the web page it's not the case.

Here's how I get my dataSource (ngOnInit) :

```js
this.users.users().subscribe(data => {
    this.dataSource.data = data;
});
```

Here's my `update` function :

```js
/**
* Update an user
* @param user The user to update
*/
  update(user: User) {
    // users = user's services
    this.users.edit(user)
    .subscribe(
      userEdited => {
        const userIndex = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(usr => usr.id === user.id);

        console.log('Before change :', this.dataSource.data[userIndex], userIndex);

        this.dataSource.data[userIndex] = userEdited;

        console.log('After change :', this.dataSource.data[userIndex], this.dataSource.data);
      }
    );
  }
```

**SOLUTION**

I need to call `renderRows()` function.

So I added a reference on my table like : `<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">`

Then I declare a `@ViewChild` property like `@ViewChild('table', { static: true }) table: MatTable<any>;`

Then :

```js
 const userIndex = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(usr => usr.id === user.id);
 console.log('Before change :', this.dataSource.data[userIndex], userIndex);
 this.dataSource.data[userIndex] = userEdited;

 this.table.renderRows(); // <--- Add this line

 console.log('After change :', this.dataSource.data[userIndex], this.dataSource.data);
```

Comment: you might need to call the renderRows() function, see https://material.angular.io/components/table/api

Comment: Can you show how you choose to render your data in your html file ?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli Thank you you're right ! I didn't know this method before !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to call the renderRows() function, see https://material.angular.io/components/table/api

> If the table's data source is a DataSource or Observable, this will be
>   invoked automatically each time the provided Observable stream emits a
>   new data array. **Otherwise if your data is an array, this function will
>   need to be called to render any changes.**

```
/**
* Update an user
* @param user The user to update
*/
update(user: User) {
  this.users.edit(user)
  .subscribe(
    userEdited => {
      const userIndex = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(usr => usr.id === user.id);
      this.dataSource.data[userIndex] = userEdited;
      this.table.renderRows(); // <--- Add this line
    }
  );
}
```